# i want to search specific record of data from dynamic data list in liferay 6.2

Tags: search, liferay-6, dynamic-data-display

i have created a database using dynamic data list 
i have to search a set of records from the database on the basis of combition
for example my database contains fields such as locality and city
and if i want to search according to this particular fields at at same time how can i do that
i am sending my snap sort of my page
here i want to search on the basis of locality,city etc

i have find some sort of solution bt exactly not getting how to carry ahead

please if any 1 can help me as soon as possible will be grateful
ThankYou

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22074587/best-way-to-include-dynamic-data-list-records-in-search-in-liferay-6-1?rq=1?

Comment: ya i have cheked that link but i dont know exactly where to write the code and what to do write